Install Cable Protection Plates Flush to Outside Edge of 2" x 8" Green Treated Wall Studs
I have a series of 2" x 8" green treated wall studs with wiring running inside. This is about 25 year old green treat lumber that is rather dense and it holds fasteners very well.
Prior to insulating the walls, covering them with plastic and plywood I want to install some cable protector plates under the plywood. The wall has Romex cable inside as well as 2" diameter metal conduit for the main power line running to a sub panel electrical box.
These protector plates are nailed into the edge of the stud via two small pointed spikes.
I need to have the top of the plates be flush with the top of the studs so there are no humps under the plywood. I am installing the plywood using finish washers as screws so it can be removed in the future in case any wiring needs to be added to the sub panel.
What would be the best technique for cutting a 1/16" deep channel the height of the plates on the outside edge of the studs?
The plates are 2 17/32" tall.
I thought about buying a cheap hand held electric plane; however, I think that might be dangerous as its not really intended for making cross cuts across the width of a board.
I could mark the depth of the inlay with a pencil and hand cut a series of grooves with a miter saw and then use a hand chisel to remove the material.
I also have a couple small new hand planes I could perhaps try using.
I need to install 25 plates so I was looking for a technique that would be consistent and fast.


"plush" or "flush"?

Do you need the plates or want them?  Those plates are needed to protect stuff that screws/nails will damage if inside ~1.5 inches of the edge.  For fast easy work, a hinge template for router might work.

I have used those plates on many projects. They never result in a noticeable bulge. Covering with plywood would be even less flat and smooth than drywall. I see no need to make the plates flush with the stud surface. The studs themselves probably are out of line more than the 1/16 inch you are concerned about.

If the wires/cables are properly located in the 2x8 (edge of holes more than 1-1/4" from the edge of the lumber) this is not required by code. The metal conduit itself meets code for protection, as well. Exceeding code is, however, fine, so long as you do meet code.
A router (very preferably with a vacuum attachment given treated lumber shavings/dust) with a template (hunk of MDF or plywood with a suitable rectangle cut in it) and a means of template following (router collars or a bearing on the router bit) is the most efficient way to do this. Choose a fairly small bit (1/2" or less for a 1/2" collet router, 1/4" for a 1/4" collet router) and take as many passes as it requires to clear all the waste - those will be much easier to control than a larger diameter bit that cuts more wood at once.
Collars are possibly less expensive and more versatile than bearing bits, but do require making the template hole oversized. Which should be easy for the very basic rectangular hole you need. The template needs to be thick enough that the bearing (not the cutter) meets the template surface; or that the collar does not protrude past the template.
Screw the template to the stud, cut the recess with the router, unscrew, repeat.
Many other ways work, but they are tedious for doing 25.

I'd be inclined to attack this with a hand-held circular saw
Set the blade depth, mark the space with a pencil and then then then free-hand groove it with the saw. tidy up with a chisel
If the the slots are slightly too tall or the edges are crooked or splintered no-one's going to see that.

Or use an oscillating multitool to skim off the face of the stud.
